# lattices made by $a\wedge b = ab$ and $a\vee b=a+b-ab$

Tags: lattice-orders

We define the binary operations $\vee$ and $\wedge$ on $\Bbb R$ by
$a\wedge b = ab$ and $a\vee b=a+b-ab$. Then for $A=\{0\}$ and $A=\{1\}$ and $A=\{0,1\}$, the set $(A,\wedge,\vee)$ is a lattice.

Is there any other $A\subset \Bbb R$ such that $(A,\wedge,\vee)$ is a lattice?

Comment: $A=[0,1],\ \mathbb{Q},\ \mathbb{Z},\ \mathbb{R}$ are another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a lattice, $\vee$ and $\wedge$ are idempotent. So here $a = a \wedge a = a^2$,  which implies...